# When using the extensions for VSCode and OpenJDK installed using homebrew, how can I find the Java Home and set it correctly?

Tags: java, setup, visualstudiocode

> While this question and answer looks more like a Java-related question, I think that this can help people starting with the Salesforce VSCode extensions and having this particular scenario (using macOS, Homebrew and OpenJDK).

One can install OpenJDK using Homebrew on MacOS, using:

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
```

and (for OpenJDK 11)

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
```

But it does not set the `JAVA_HOME` *automagically* as one might expect.

How can I find the Java Home to edit my `settings.json` in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't set the `JAVA_HOME` automatically. But you can find the folder location using another command.

It creates a "java_home" executable under `/usr/libexec`. You can then use the following command to find your Java Home:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11
```

It displays the full path you can copy to your VSCode settings:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then in your `settings.json` you can set it like:

```
{
    ...

    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/",

    ... 
}
```